# How to load dynamic content in PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, dynamic

I am looking to use PhoneGap as my framework for an app that I will be developing for iOS and Android.

The client has a CMS that has already been fitted with a web service allowing us to generate a clean HTML page with the content. (Text and images)

Our goal is to allow the client to update his application with his CMS. What we thought could work best was to load the HTML generated by our CMS web service and inject it into the specified PhoneGap page. This would allow the client to have a dynamic application that he can manage certain pages through his CMS.

I have read that using a web view will NOT be accepted by Apple, so consider that we obviously want the app to be approved in your replies.

How would we go into getting a web service to load the dynamic content into the PhoneGap App and be approved by Apple?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you planning to uplaod this app to the appstore or will the app be sued only by internal employees?

Answer (score 1):

Loading an entire HTML page is not a wise move. It would be better to let the webservice output JSON wich you can then read with your app. Phonegap is html based so you can build a DOM from the json.

If you want to generate a full HTML page on the server then you can add the result of the service to your DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Where would I go to learn more about reading the JSON output on my app? And by developing the webservice with a JSON output, will Apple have any problems by doing it this way? I would then format the JSON output with CSS/Javascript in my app.

Comment: JSON is a data format based on javascript. http://www.json.org/js.html that site should give you all the information you need about json.